# Problem using eclipse WindowBuilder and JCA-JCE methods

Tags: java, encryption, windowbuilder

I'm doing an independent project by myself about encryption/decryption message using JCA-JCE and WindowBuilder as GUI.

My problem is when the cipher has to encrypt the message and convert that in a ciphertext this Exception came out every time

javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length not multiple of 16 bytes

I try it without GUI first and everything went ok

now I will show you the code but please don't be rude on me for the confusion of the code lol it's just a "prototype"

Thanks to everyone who can help me

```
    import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class GUI2 extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField txtInsert;


    static Cipher ecipher;
    static SecretKey key;
    static byte[] mex;
    static String alg;
    int index;
    static byte[] ciphertext;
    String uno=new String("k");
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    GUI2 frame = new GUI2();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException 
     */
    public GUI2() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 602, 408);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblInserisciTesto = new JLabel("Inserisci Testo");
        lblInserisciTesto.setBounds(29, 33, 190, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblInserisciTesto);

        /////////////////TEXTFIELD////////////////
        txtInsert = new JTextField();
        mex=uno.getBytes("UTF-8");
        txtInsert.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                mex=txtInsert.getText().getBytes("UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
        });{
        txtInsert.setText("INSERT");
        txtInsert.setBounds(276, 30, 284, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtInsert);
        txtInsert.setColumns(10);


        }


        ///////////////LABEL SELEZIONA ALGORITMO/////////////
        JLabel lblSelezionaAlgoritmo = new JLabel("Seleziona Algoritmo");
        lblSelezionaAlgoritmo.setBounds(29, 109, 104, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblSelezionaAlgoritmo); 





        ///////////////BUTTON//////////////////////////////
        JButton btnCrypt = new JButton("CRYPT");{
        btnCrypt.setBounds(223, 316, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnCrypt);


        btnCrypt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {     /////ACTION
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if((index>=0)&&(index<4)) {
                try {
                    SecureRandom random=new SecureRandom();
                    KeyGenerator keygen=KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
                    keygen.init(256,random);
                    key=keygen.generateKey();
                    ecipher=Cipher.getInstance(alg);
                    ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,key);
                    ciphertext = ecipher.doFinal(mex);
                    System.out.println(ciphertext);

                } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException  e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                }else if((index>=4)&&(index<7)) {

                }

            }
        });
        }
        //////////////COMBOBOX//////////////////
        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
        comboBox.setBounds(276, 105, 284, 22);

        String a=new String("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
        String b=new String("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        String c=new String("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
        String d=new String("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        String f=new String("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        String g=new String("DES/ECB/NoPadding");
        String h=new String("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");

        comboBox.addItem(a);
        comboBox.addItem(b);
        comboBox.addItem(c);
        comboBox.addItem(d);
        comboBox.addItem(f);
        comboBox.addItem(g);
        comboBox.addItem(h);
        contentPane.add(comboBox);

        comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                alg=(String) comboBox.getSelectedItem();
                index=comboBox.getSelectedIndex();
            }
        });{


        }




        JLabel lblCiphertext = new JLabel("CipherText");
        lblCiphertext.setBounds(29, 204, 104, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblCiphertext);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("New label");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(276, 195, 284, 23);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this list:

```
    String a=new String("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
    String b=new String("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    String c=new String("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
    String d=new String("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    String f=new String("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    String g=new String("DES/ECB/NoPadding");
    String h=new String("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
```

If you use a cipher with `NoPadding`, you need to provide data that align to the block size of the encryption cipher. If you specify a padding, the provider will ensure your data is correctly padded for you, and thus you will avoid the `javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException`

Comment: ok but my GUI first have to decide what algorithm use and then create the cipher so I don't really understand what I have to fix

Comment: You get the error from an actual encrypt. Your input to encrypt is the byte value of the letter 'k' as this is hardcoded in your code. If you select a cipher with NoPadding from your list, you will get the error you describe, as 1 byte is not a multiplum of 16 bytes.

Comment: Just a last question how can I write inside a label the byte[] ciphertext?